# MySQL show relations MANY-MANY by condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are two tables:

**partner**

```
id | name
--------------
1  | partner_1
2  | partner_2
3  | partner_3
4  | partner_4
```

**contract**

```
id | name       | is_active
---------------------------
1  | contract_1 | 1
2  | contract_2 | 0
3  | contract_3 | 1
4  | contract_4 | 0
5  | contract_5 | 0
```

There is a third table that relates the previous two tables with **many-to-many** relationship

**partner_contract**

```
partner_id | contract_id
------------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 3
2          | 2
2          | 4
3          | 5
```

Each partner can have several contracts, among which **ONLY ONE** can be active and some inactive .
Also the partner may not have contract at all.

I need a query that displays all the partners together with the active contract. If partner dont' have an active contract, display NULL.

```
partner_id | partner_name | contract_name
-----------------------------------------
1          | partner_1    | contract_1
2          | partner_2    | contract_3
3          | partner_3    | NULL
4          | partner_4    | NULL
```

I found a solution, but it seems to me that it is not perfect .

```
SELECT
    p.id AS partner_id,
    p.name AS partner_name,
    active_contract.name AS contract_name
FROM partner p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM contract c
    LEFT JOIN partner_contract pc on pc.contract_id = c.id
    WHERE c.is_active = 1
) active_contract
ON active_contract.partner_id = p.id
```

**Is there a more elegant solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ray's (deleted) query is close to the right solution. The condition on the contract should go in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause:

```
SELECT p.id AS partner_id, p.name AS partner_name, c.name AS contract_name
FROM partner p LEFT JOIN
     partner_contract pc
     ON p.id = pc.partner_id LEFT JOIN
     contract c
     ON pc.contract_id = c.id AND c.is_active = 1;
```

EDIT:

Okay, the above is wrong.  This can be fixed with a `group by`:

```
SELECT p.id AS partner_id, p.name AS partner_name, MAX(c.name) AS contract_name
FROM partner p LEFT JOIN
     partner_contract pc
     ON p.id = pc.partner_id LEFT JOIN
     contract c
     ON pc.contract_id = c.id AND c.is_active = 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.name;
```

The more elegant solution (in my opinion):

```
SELECT p.*,
       (select name
        from partner_contract pc join
             contract c
             on pc.contract_id = c.id AND c.is_active = 1
        where p.id = pc.partner_id
       ) as contract_name
FROM partner p;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cc9/5/1)

This can take advantage of indexes and does not require aggregation.

Comment: You solution displays duplicate partners. But I need the result, which is given in the question.

Comment: @elementfani . . . Sorry about that.  I was so focused on the `on` versus `where` clauses that I missed that obvious case.

Comment: **@Gordon Linoff**, you had some errors in your last query, that I fixed for you.  I also provided the Fiddle.